# NetLogo: Make turtles fear each other

Tags: netlogo

As a NetLogo learner (beginner) I am working on a small project. I was trying to write a small code were I would like to make the turtles fear each other. So walk away from each other. Can anybody please assist met with this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

In the Flocking model in the NetLogo Models Library (under Sample Models -> Biology), the birds are attracted to each other (if they drift far apart) yet also repel each other (if they get too close). You might try just taking Flocking and moving the sliders, or tweaking the code, to get the behavior you're asking for?

You might also look at Heatbugs (also under Biology iirc), where some of the bugs seek company and others want to avoid it.

Finally, check out the Scatter model, under Social Science -- the turtles all move away from each other.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `layout-spring`. Usually it is used in combination with links, but works also without them. Minimal example:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 20 [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go 
  layout-spring turtles no-links 0.2 5 1
  tick
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Very usefull

Answer (score 1):

I have used

```
ask turtles [face one-of other turtles bk .1]
```

and

```
ask turtles [if any? other turtles in-radius 4 [face towards one-of other turtles in-radius 4 bk .1]]
```

or when I wanted turtles to scare other turtles

```
ask turtles [ask other turtles in-radius 2 [face myself bk .1]]
```